# Default file open of the same software from windows explorer in the appropriate file versions

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, adobe-flash

I have Adobe Flash CS3 and Adobe Flash CS4 installed on Windows 7 PC. The problem is that i can set the default to either of the applications but i can't seem to set it to open the appropriate file types.

For eg: I want the files that I create in Flash CS3 to open in the same version i.e. Flash CS3, and the Flash CS4 files to open automatically in the Flash CS4 is there a way to do this? (i.e. If I am opening the files from windows explorer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file extensions are different then yes you can. Otherwise it looks like the answer is

## No.

You can however right click and open with a specific application [`Open With...`]. If you know what files are CS3 and CS4 then it will be a minor nuance to do this. If they are all jumbled together then you may have more difficulty.

Comment: well that's how I do it normally, I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it apparently not I suppose!